# Android data backup which survives factory reset/device wipe

Tags: android, synchronization, google-cloud-messaging, backup, device

I want to create a **unique identification** for a pair **(device, user)** to sync with cloud everytime given user installs the application on **given device**, but I *also* want to keep track of **different devices**.

The *problem* is that once the device is set to **factory settings**, the [ANDROID_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) is *reset as well*. And since there is not way to get any stable unique android device identification (for both tablets and mobile devices) I am unable to keep track of the device.

Is there any way to **store an application data** in order for them to **survive** the **factory reset/device wipe**? I'm assuming to do this only if the user logs in with the same google account.

EDIT: I have ended up using UUID composed of 3 components:
  - The User Handle ID
  - Mac Address of the Wifi Adapter
  - The International Mobile Equipment Identity (IMEI)

Though not 100% reliable (with regards to rooted devices and someone trying to overcome it), this turns out to be quite functional.

Comment: Fortunately, no. Malware authors would think that your plan is *awesome*, where they can have their malware survive a factory reset.

Comment: I am interested only in the data, not the application itself thou.

Comment: That does not matter much. Incomplete factory resets/wipes are considered to be a security flaw.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm assuming to do this only if the user logs in with the same google account. Maybe the Android Backup Service could be of help?

Comment: Possibly, though IIRC, users can control whether or not backups are made.

Comment: I don't know if it fits your use case, but Google Play Services offers [an instance ID service](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/).

Comment: Sadly the instance ID is highly volatile regarding the application changes.